# Separating elements of a list into many elements inside it and selecting one of the elements by a condition

Tags: python

I have my list:

```
l = ['a;b;c;2:38', 'd;e;f;3:16', 'g;h;i;3:20']
```

I want to separate it in:

```
l = [[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['2:38']], [['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['3:16']], [['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['3:20']]]
```

This is because I have to select the first element of one of the lists (a, d, or g) by the condition if the last element (the number) is greater than an int input. So I thought it would be easier to transform the list but I don't know how to do it.
In this example, I receive the number 190 and I want to make a function that returns the first element of the list that has the number that is greater than this input (in this case 190), this happens with the 3:16 (3 minutes and 16 seconds are 196 seconds) and the 3:20 (3 minutes and 20 seconds are 200 seconds), so my function would return:

```
['d','g']
```

I tried doing something like:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
  l[i] = l[i].split(",")
```

And then doing it with the ';' but it doesn't do what I want.
I'm also complicated with the part of evaluating if the minutes in the list are greater than "n" seconds.

Comment: `[[[[y] for y in x.split("; ")] for x in l]]` will output a list in the format that you ask for, though I don't quite understand what it is needed for.

Comment: Could you explain better your second question? Why is there only ['b'] ,['c'], and not the other supposed: ['h'], ['i']?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, I will fix it!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `d` and `g`? Also, is there a reason you need each component to be a list of lists? In other words, instead of `[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['2:38']]`, it would probably be simpler to use `['a', 'b', 'c', '2:38']`, a list of strings. (Or for that matter, `['a', 'b', 'c', 158]`.)

Comment: oh yes I messed up again. And no, it isn't necessary to be a list of lists

Comment: See my answer @queenbegop777, it will do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To create the list of list you want:

```
l = ['a; b; c; 2:38', 'd; e; f; 3:16', 'g; h; i; 3:20']

newl=[[[[ele]for ele in i.split('; ')] for i in l]] 

print(newl)
```

You could try this, instead of creating the list of lists to get the desired output:

```
l = ['a; b; c; 2:38', 'd; e; f; 3:16', 'g; h; i; 3:20']


def get_sec(time_str):
    return sum(int(x) * 60 ** i for i,x in enumerate(reversed(time_str.split(":"))))

def func(ls, inp):
    allow=filter(lambda x: get_sec('0:'+x.split('; ')[-1])>inp , ls)
    return [x[0] for x in allow]

inp=190  #input
ge=func(l,inp)

print(ge)
```

Output:

```
['d', 'g']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need.

```
l = ['a;b;c;2:38', 'd;e;f;3:16', 'g;h;i;3:20']


list(map(lambda x: [[i] for i in x], map(lambda x: x.split(';'), l)))
```

```
[[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['2:38']],
 [['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['3:16']],
 [['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['3:20']]]
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! Now I'm trying to figure out how to work out the condition of the seconds I explained in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can use a list comprehension:

```
l = ['a;b;c;2:38', 'd;e;f;3:16', 'g;h;i;3:20']

l = [[[a] for a in s.split(';')] for s in l]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['2:38']], 
 [['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['3:16']], 
 [['g'], ['h'], ['i'], ['3:20']]]
```